# Looking for C# code to work with .PAR2 archives

Tags: c#

I was looking for some C# or VB.NET code that works with .PAR2 archives (see http://www.par2.net/par2spec.php if ths doesn't ring a bell for you!).  I've looked all over but I've have yet to find anything useful.  If at all possible I'd like to leverage some existing work instead of writing from scratch so any suggestions would be helpful...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to leverage existing work, is to use Interop to call a native library capable of handling PAR2 archives, and just write a .NET wrapper for it.

Avoid reinventing the wheel, unless there is some reason NIH line of thought is required?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!  Unfortunately, I'm looking for a native library or source code...